# Is there a performance impact by having a lot of folders in the system PATH?

Tags: linux, windows, environment-variables, path

Is it okay to have a lot of folders added to the system PATH (in either Windows or Linux), or is there a performance impact? (while booting, or while opening a terminal, etc.)

Comment: The answer is likely different in Linux and Windows, due to how filesystems are handled in both. Likely much less a problem in Linux. In both cases the other of directories in the path could make a difference. But I would worry more about the management problem than the performance one.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas *ABSOLUTELY BAD!* Measurements?

Comment: Maybe it was "absolutely bad" in MS-DOS (where directory lookups would result in disk access every single time), but Windows and Linux _do_ cache directory entries in RAM ([including nonexistent entries](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/negative_dentries.html)), so I have my doubts about it having a huge impact.